# Little Im in solutions When solving equation with a Solve

Tags: equation-solving

I am dealing with a normal equation:

```
ClearAll[equ, r, x, ans`vt];
r = 4/100;
equ = 7*x^3 - (8*r + 8)*x^2 + (12*r - 6)*x + 4 == 0;
ans`vt = Solve[equ, x]
```

When I use Solve,I can get analytical solution:

```
{{x -> 208/
    525 - ((1 + I Sqrt[3]) (-4870219 + 525 I Sqrt[1319277153])^(
     1/3))/(525 2^(2/3)) - (57857 (1 - I Sqrt[3]))/(
    525 (2 (-4870219 + 525 I Sqrt[1319277153]))^(1/3))}, {x -> 
   208/525 - ((1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-4870219 + 525 I Sqrt[1319277153])^(
     1/3))/(525 2^(2/3)) - (57857 (1 + I Sqrt[3]))/(
    525 (2 (-4870219 + 525 I Sqrt[1319277153]))^(1/3))}, {x -> 
   1/525 (208 + (57857 2^(2/3))/(-4870219 + 525 I Sqrt[1319277153])^(
      1/3) + (2 (-4870219 + 525 I Sqrt[1319277153]))^(1/3))}}
```

This solutions includes Im, But I find it should not have Im,When I use NSolve,I get:

```
ans`vt = NSolve[equ, x]
{{x -> -0.77612}, {x -> 0.504079}, {x -> 1.46061}}
```

When I turn Solve solutions into N:

```
ans`vt = Solve[equ, x] // N
{{x -> 0.504079 + 2.22045*10^-16 I}, {x -> -0.77612 - 
    1.11022*10^-16 I}, {x -> 1.46061 - 1.08273*10^-16 I}}
```

I think it may be a precision problem, but I don't know Exactly why, can someone tell me about this?

Comment: The numerical value of your expressions is $$\{0.504079\, +\text{3.3306690738754696$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-16} i,-0.77612-\text{1.1102230246251565$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-16} i,1.46061\, -\text{1.0827317878249146$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-16} i\}$$ Notice the value of the imaginaries? Take you analytical results and try N[%] of those.

Comment: The presence of the constant `I` does not necessarily mean that the results are complex . See [`Casus irreducibilis`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis)

Comment: Use `Solve[equ, x]` and you will see that the three roots are real and expressed as `Root` expressions. `N` will convert the `Root` expressions, i.e., `Solve[equ, x]//N`